# Go Worker Pool doesn't seem to be processing Concurrently

Tags: concurrency, go

Hello I'm brand new to go (and concurrent programming in general :() and trying to distribute a slow computation to a pool of workers.

http://play.golang.org/p/lTv4Tm75A4

```
func main() {
    test := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
    answer := getSmallestMultiple(test)
    fmt.Println(answer)
}
```

I am trying to find the smallest number that is evenly divisible by all the numbers in `test`.

I have created a pool of workers and am sending them values until one of the goroutines finds a number that can be evenly divided by all the numbers in `test`

```
for w := 0; w < 100; w++ {
    go divisibleByAllNumbers(&numbers, jobs, answer)
}


go func() {
    for i := max; ; i += max {
        fmt.Printf("Sending # %d\n", i)
        jobs <- i
    }
}()
```

The program seems to be running at the same speed despite how many workers I start. I have tried many number of workers and it always takes the same number of seconds to run, which seems like the work is not being done concurrently at all.

Each worker is consuming work from the queue using `range`:

```
for j := range jobs {}
```

And i was hoping the more processes consuming off the `jobs` channel the faster the program would execute.

I have also tried different values for the `jobs := make(chan int)` buffer value

I have stared at this all day and was hoping someone could see what the issue is.  I would expect the more workers I add the faster the computation takes but am not experiencing that.  I'm sure I"m missing some key concepts,

Thank you

Comment: What is your setting for GOMAXPROCS?

Comment: When GOMAXPROCS is 1 a goroutine are more like thread than a process so you can't get more speed out a single CPU core. This is useful when you have some blocking I/O but does not help in your code. Increasing GOMAXPROCS should help, because the go runtime will split the goroutines across multiple processes.

Comment: Processors or processes @TheHippo? They're ... kinda different :P

Comment: @SimonWhitehead I think I got it right. Increasing GOMAXPROCS will make sure your program will use multiple processes and therefore has a change to use multiple processors.

Comment: @TheHippo: `GOMAXPROCS` sets the number of OS *threads* that will be used to schedule user goroutines. There is only ever 1 process (for the conventional definition of "process").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#parallel

The current implementation of the Go runtime will not parallelize this code by default. It dedicates only a single core to user-level processing. An arbitrary number of goroutines can be blocked in system calls, but by default only one can be executing user-level code at any time. It should be smarter and one day it will be smarter, but until it is if you want CPU parallelism you must tell the run-time how many goroutines you want executing code simultaneously. There are two related ways to do this. Either run your job with environment variable GOMAXPROCS set to the number of cores to use or import the runtime package and call runtime.GOMAXPROCS(NCPU). A helpful value might be runtime.NumCPU(), which reports the number of logical CPUs on the local machine. Again, this requirement is expected to be retired as the scheduling and run-time improve.

Comment: Note, due to scheduler improvements, for go1.5 `GOMAXPROCS` will now default to `runtime.NumCPU()` (though the `runtime.GOMAXPROCS` call still remains, since NumCPU isn't universally optimal)